# SQL take max of similar id's from join

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to more advanced SQL queries

**Given the following tables and associated fields:**

**Person**
PersonId, FirstName, LastName

**Order**
OrderId, PersonId, OrderDateTime

I want to write a query that will join both tables by PersonId and will retrieve every person and their most recent order.

So if James Doe (PersonId = 1) below has many orders in the orders table,

**OrderId, PersonId, OrderDateTime**

```
1          1          12/1/2013 9:01 AM

2          1          2/1/2011 5:01 AM

3          2          10/1/2010 1:10 AM
```

it will only take the most recent for his.

**PersonId NameFirst NameLast OrderId OrderDateTime**

```
1 James Doe 1    12/1/2013 9:01 AM 

2 John Doe 3     10/1/2010 1:10 AM
```

I have been trying something like this

```
SELECT p.PersonID, o.OrderID, MAX(o.OrderDateTime) From Person p
JOIN Orders o ON p.PersonID = o.PersonID
GROUP BY p.PersonID,
```

Thanks

Comment: Unless you really are using both MySQL and SQL Server, only tag with the tag for the dbms you're actually using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner query in this solution is a temporary table containing the most recent orders for each person.  I join this back to the `Orders` table to get the fields you want, and then join again to the `Person` table.

```
SELECT p.PersonID, p.NameFirst, p.NameLast, o.OrderID, o.OrderDateTime
FROM Person p INNER JOIN Orders o
ON o.PersonId = p.PersonId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT o1.PersonId, MAX(o1.OrderDateTime) AS maxTime
    FROM Orders o1
    GROUP BY o1.PersonId
) t
ON o.PersonId = t.PersonId AND o.OrderDateTime = t.maxTime
```

Comment: @jpw You are completely correct.  I updated my query.

Comment: I'm betting that he's using MySQL, and G-d help us all if he's using SQL-Server.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen ok thats what I was wondering too just didn't know if i knew what I was talking about. But this makes sense and it's a great answer and I thank you very much

Comment: and I'm using both, two different computers. But for this problem I wasn't actually using anything yet it was just a conceptual thing

Answer (score 2):

You can use variables to simulate `ROW_NUMBER` not available in MySQL:

```
SELECT p.PersonId, FirstName, LastName, 
       o.OrderId, o.OrderDateTime
FROM Person AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT OrderId, OrderDateTime, PersonId,
         @row_number := IF(@pid <> PersonId,
                           IF(@pid:=PersonId, 1, 1),
                           IF(@pid:=PersonId, @row_number+1, @row_number+1)) AS rn
  FROM `Order`
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @pid := 0) vars
  ORDER BY OrderDateTime DESC
) AS o  ON p.PersonId = o.PersonId AND o.rn = 1
```

`rn = 1` for the top level record within each `PersonId` slice of the derived table. Using this predicate in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` we can match each row of `Person` to the most recent row of `Order` and obtain *all* `Order` fields.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12828/2)

**EDIT:**

In SQL-Server the query looks like this:

```
SELECT p.*, o.OrderId, o.OrderDateTime
FROM Person AS p
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT *, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId 
                             ORDER BY OrderDateTime DESC) AS rn
   FROM [Order]
) AS o ON p.PersonId = o.PersonId AND o.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So the most recent order per every person.  You could do something like this:

```
select p.*, o.*
from person p
inner join orders o on p.personId = o.personId
inner join (
    -- get the max order per person
    SELECT max(orderId) as orderId, personId
    from orders
    group by personId
) maxOrder on o.orderId = maxOrder.orderId
```

joining `o` onto `maxOrder` on the `orderId` filters the result set only to the orders that are also the maximum order per customer.

Note that I used the `ID` on the table rather than the datetime, as the ID is guaranteed to be unique (for help with joins) - this is not always available depending on the nature of the use in the table, but it looks like it should work for your case.